# authorizing users that have not registered or logged in

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authorize

I am working on an question-answer website about **AIDS**.

Users can send their Confidential questions via a simple form. then we give them a unique code to tracking question and see their answers.

All question shown generally But who asked the question is not clear.

We do not want to register users Because the person who asked the question about AIDS, not like his identity compromised.

Because of that, we used a simple code that give it them after sending question.

In this case, suppose after one week ,user comes back (and want to see his answer or continue qustion-answer)but Forgot his code.Now beacuse user not registered before ,he can not do anything.

what is best approach in this case that user not registered. how can authorize users that have not logged in and registered?

Comment: If you want to maintain anonymity there should be absolutely no way, for you or anybody else, to identify a user that has lost his token/code.

Comment: Maybe let the user choose their own token rather than generate it for them. I guess they'll less likely forget that. Or add a field where the user can enter a phrase which he can use to retrieve his question along with the date he asked.

Comment: You can send mail to that user with their unique code.

Comment: @A.D,Based on previous our experiences, These kinds of users are afraid to even the smallest data compromised , So do not leave their emails and they are discouraged from asking questions

Comment: You should not be able to track such users (which is basically what the question boils down to). Just be strict in that if they lose their code, they can't recover it.

Answer (score 0):

every moment question create, user can give that code + set cookie with content which set by that code. if user forget code, website can read cookie's content and match to question

really simple and easy :D

Comment: Unless the users are browsing in incognito. But it's something.

Comment: @apokryfos yesterday I read something about evercookie. maybe he can use it: https://github.com/samyk/evercookie

Comment: @Andrew it's disrespectful to a user's wishes to not be tracked (in the least)

Comment: @Andrew LOL it's deepened who use it and why. in our languge (farsi) we have a proverb that say: "It's a double-edged sword" !